# LINQ Combine Groups and get distinct maximum number of occurances

Tags: linq, count, grouping, distinct

I have a number of lists of items in the form of two int values called basketId, ProductNameId which have been selected and persisted. for example  {{1,1} {1,2}, {1,3}}  through to some upper basketId  {{n,2} {n,6}, {n,6},{n,6},{n,7},{n,8}}. The number of baskets varies and the number of entries per basket can vary.

I need the output in the form of ProductNameId and Max Count for each ID present across all the sets of baskets. For the two shown above this would be:
1,1, 2,1, 3,1, 6,3, 7,1, 8,1

I have the following code and it works but it seems ugly and long winded, so I'm asking for a little help to come up with a better way / more concise - maybe single statement that does the same.

```
// Get all the baskets that have been saved
var baskets = Baskets.Where(x => x.MarketId == 1);

// Group and get count for each product in each basket
var counts = from q1 in all
group q1 by new 
{
    q1.ProductNameId,
    q1.BasketId
}
into g
select new
{
    ProductNameId = g.Key.ProductNameId,
    Count = g.Count ()
};

// Group products and find the Maximum count that exists
var max = from q2 in counts
group q2 by q2.ProductNameId
into g
select new
{
    ProductNameId = g.Key,
    Max = g.Max (x => x.Count)
};

// The distinct set of values present
var distinct = max.Distinct();
```

Comment: Can you clarify your data further? Is it essentially `List<Basket>` where basket has two ints of `ProductNameId` and `BasketId`? And, if so, what does some sample data look like and what are you trying to get from it?

Comment: So if for example you had this: { 
                {1,1}, 
                {1,2}, 
                {1,3},
                {1,2}, 
                {1,3},
                {2,2}, 
                {2,3},
                {1,4}, 
                {1,5}
            } would you expect this result: ?  {ProductNameId = 1, Max = 1}, {ProductNameId = 2, Max = 3}, {ProductNameId = 3, Max = 3}, {ProductNameId = 4, Max = 1}, {ProductNameId = 5, Max = 1},

Comment: Basket is essentially a item with two columns, BasketId (which shopping basket has contents) and ProductNameId (what product type has been purchased). There are hundreds of unique BasketId records in any one day and for each of the distinct BasketId values there are typically between 5 and 50 ProductNameId values. Some of these values appear more than once when a customer purchases  more than one of the same product type. They could for example purchase two different makes of cereal or Confectionery the basket will contain two records

Comment: eburgos, yes that output is what I would expect if your example basket was used as the input. But in my case there are 100's of different baskets and they all need to be considered at the same time, each with a set of unique and diverse productNameId's across all the baskets (each shopping basket sold has a different set of product types, some types of product may occur many times)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your underlying data is still a little mysterious to me, but from what your code looks like, I believe you are trying to do this:

```
// Get all the baskets that have been saved  
var baskets = Baskets.Where(x => x.MarketId == 1);  

// Group and get count for each product in each basket 
var distinct = from q1 in baskets 
    group q1 by q1.ProductNameId into g
    select new
    {
        ProductNameId = g.Key,
        Max = (from q2 in g
            group q2.BasketId by q2.BasketId).Max (x => x.Count())
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fairly straight forward way to do it:

```
var query =
    baskets
        .ToLookup(b => b.ProductNameId)
        .Select(l => new
        {
            ProductNameId = l.Key,
            Max = l.Count(),
        });
```

Comment: Sorry, but that does not work correctly. The Max value produced here actually contains the count of ProductNameId across all baskets processed. When i ran it on my sample the Max value produced was 132 items with productNameId == 1, Which it the total number of ProductNameId == 1 values in all the baskets. The actual maximum number of ProductNameId == 1 existing in any one basket was 3. I need this value not the count that exists  across all baskets.